# Why isn't my button enabling when text is added to the textbox with Fody.PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, fody

I am using Fody.PropertyChanged to try and reduce some of the boilerplate code in my WPF project.

When I tried to create a button click event, it appeared that Fody would not handle this in the same way that it handled the binding between, for example, a label and a string property.

I have a textbox and I want a button to be enabled / disabled depending on whether this textbox has text. My XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
   <Label Content="Enter text:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

   <TextBox Height="100" 
      TextWrapping="Wrap" 
      Text="{Binding Test}" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Padding="5, 3, 1, 1"
      AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="161,10,10,0"/>

   <Button Content="Go" 
      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=GoButtonIsEnabled}"
      Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClick}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="64,158,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel it is bound to is:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ButtonCommandBinding ButtonClick { get; set; }
    public bool GoButtonIsEnabled => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Test);

    public string Test { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new ButtonCommandBinding(OnGoButtonClick);
    }

    private void OnGoButtonClick()
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!");
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The ButtonCommandBinding:

```
public class ButtonCommandBinding : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action handler;
    private bool isEnabled;

    public ButtonCommandBinding(Action handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != isEnabled)
            {
                isEnabled = value;
                CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            handler();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the reason that typing in the textbox isn't enabling the button is because the property changed notifier isn't being called.. but I am not calling it because I am using Fody. I had not implemented `NotifyPropertyChanged` in my ViewModel until I tried getting to button click working; before implementing the button click this was handled by Fody (when I was just binding a label to text).

So I have two questions:

1. Am I misunderstanding, or grossly misusing, the purpose of Fody?
2. Why doesn't the button enable when the Test property is no longer null or whitespace?

EDIT: Thanks to ANu for telling me to add the [AlsoNotifyFor(nameof(GoButtonIsEnabled))] attribute. However, the issue I now have is that when I load the textbox with text set in the ViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Test = "Enter text here";
    ButtonClick = new ButtonCommandBinding(OnButtonClick);
    ButtonClick.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

...and I run the app and then delete the text from the textbox, the Go button doesn't disable until I click it. After I click it, the action doesn't run (as it shouldn't, because textbox is empty) and the button disabled. When I enter text into the textbox, it does not re-enable.

It seems the binding still isn't working properly.

```
public bool GoButtonIsEnabled => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Test);

[AlsoNotifyFor(nameof(GoButtonIsEnabled))]
public string Test { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Test = "Enter text";
    ButtonClick = new ButtonCommandBinding(OnButtonClick);
    ButtonClick.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Go" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding Path=GoButtonIsEnabled}"
   Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClick}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="64,158,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Comment: You have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your class but dont use it. Change your Test property to notify the change of the Test and GoButtonIsEnabled  in the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fody would inject notify code for each Property as you desired. However, you also want to Notify a depended property(`GoButtonIsEnabled`) when another property(`Text`) is changed..

You would need to use [AlsoNotifyFor](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes#alsonotifyforattribute) attribute to allows the injection of notify code that points to a different property.

```
[AlsoNotifyFor(nameof(GoButtonIsEnabled ))]
public string Test { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding the AlsoNotifyFor attribute to the Test property still does not work.

Comment: Hope you have added <PropertyChanged/> to FodyWeavers.xml ?

Comment: Hi Anu. It was something else. The binding still isn't working; I have updated the question, if you could have a look?

Comment: Doesn't work, sometimes `Fody` confuses me, the code is the same but some properties don't get notified (especially read-only properties)

Answer (score 0):

**Fody/PropertyChanged** does not support notification of nested references, use **PostSharp** instead. 或者使用免费的 `CalculatedProperties`[CalculatedProperties](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties).

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class Person
{
    public bool IsNameNotEmpty => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsNameNotEmpty => SomePerson.IsNameNotEmpty;
    public Person? SomePerson { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsNameNotEmpty}"  // Can not notify!
IsEnabled="{Binding SomePerson.IsNameNotEmpty}" // Can notify!
```

[image]